# Debugging non-reachable nodes in IP networks

Tags: routing

I have 3 nodes in my (IP) network:

A  --  B  --  C

A is connected to B and B is connected to C.
I need to access A from C, and vice-versa.

- C = 192.168.224.3
- B = 192.168.224.1, 192.168.223.146
- A =                192.168.223.2

From C, I'm able to ping both IP@ of B (224.1 and 223.146).
But the ping to A (223.2) fails.

What would have I overlooked?
I'm pasting the route table details of the three nodes below.

#### C's route table

- Destination     Gateway        Interface
- 192.168.223.0    192.168.224.1    eth1

#### B's route table

- Destination      Gateway       Interface
- 192.168.223.0    192.168.223.146  eol23
- 192.168.224.0    192.168.224.1    eob0

#### A's route table

- Destination      Gateway       Interface
- 192.168.223.0    192.168.223.2    eol23
- 192.168.224.0    192.168.223.2    eol23

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The routing tables aren't much help without us knowing which interface is which. Please provide a more detailed network description. Also, some more configuration details and information about the devices used can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Your diagnostic

> From C, I'm able to ping both IP@ of B (224.1 and 223.146). But the
>   ping to A (223.2) fails.

I can decide - problem most probable in routing from A to C (on A node)

Checking routing tables Im found incorrect route to BC network.

```
192.168.224.0 192.168.223.2 eol23
```

must be

```
192.168.224.0 192.168.223.146 eol23
```